# Installing GApps on an old bargain tablet (Impression i10a)

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-apps

I recently was given a free tablet that is turning out to be more trouble than it is worth. I've been trying for weeks to get some form of GApps installed. I've read through the only resource I've found on the device and had little success. [I'm currently the last poster on this thread.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1151330&page=31)

> I have a i10a which came preloaded with ICS 4.0.3. I used Root_with_Restore_by_Bin4ry_v32 to get full root (it came sorta rooted). I'm having trouble finding a gapps package that works right.
>
> I've used:
>   gapps-hdpi-20100817-Impression_10 from the second post
>   and
>   gapps-ics-20120429
>   both of which would crash at the setup wizard endlessly.
>
> I finally got through to the launcher after using gapps-ics-20120224 which was the closest number to what the build number was 
>   (i10a 0.1.05 eng.root.20120223.R&G)
>
> But any gapps I try crash almost instantly. I don't really know what other packages to try at this point...

Is it possible that there is just no version of GApps that would install properly on this device or is it just a matter of going through every one? Is there some strategy to finding the correct package beyond "it must be 4.0 compatible"?

Comment: It's entirely possible that no version will work. You're trying to run software on hardware it wasn't designed for, by a manufacturer who wouldn't shell out for Google to support it.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this on a cheap tablet before, really all there is to it, is to get clockworkmod installed on the device, then flash cyanogenmod's gapps onto it.....unfortunately I did a little bit of digging, and wasn't able to come up with much as far as getting clockworkmod installed onto that particular device....there was one point in time where you could just flash the market/play store apk directly onto the device, however these days it requires the full blown framework to run correctly, so you can't just flash the apk separate, but rather you need to flash the whole zip file in recovery.

Comment: What is the difference between installing the apks and flashing the gapps packages?

Comment: Not entirely sure to be quite honest, but I know on my tablet, i tried flashing the apps separately, and it wouldn't take until i flashed the zip file in recovery directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read that if you install the APKs that you have to do them in a certain order and possibly reboot in between them, so maybe flashing them all at once avoids all that. Regardless, I'm looking into building my own CWM, but considering that someone much smarter than I in that thread gave up on the pursuit, I'm not expecting much success.

Comment: http://goo-inside.me/gapps/gapps-ics-20120317-signed.zip  you can try and pull apart that zip and install the files in the correct order...being that they are basically an untampered, plain version of gapps built specifically for ics....that's probably your best bet.  Let me know if you can get it up and working via the install order that was given.